# Pedantic tw*t - correct usage

Tags: discussion

I have two questions:

Do the members of this forum think that the number of hoops that one needs to jump through to post here is counter-productive to the exploration of the subject at hand?

Can the words "Pedantic twat" be used to accurately describe any of the moderators here? I have found one example but I am not sure if it's an exception or a rule.

Thank you to the two members who welcomed my question but heavy-handed moderation has made this a very unwelcoming forum and I doubt I will be returning.

Tom

Comment: StackExchange sites are usually pretty brutal in my experience. I can only wish you good luck, sir.

Comment: Also, this question is hilarious... however, it is probably also too "opinion based" and so technically "off topic".

Comment: They've been extremely helpful to me. Best English forum out there. The moderators take pride in quality control. That's what separates this site from others.

Comment: Yeah, also you use the term "moderators", but really the whole community has an influence over everything - so, I'd say the Mods are not necessarily at fault in your complaint - and that, rather, it's that there are many "pedantic twats" out there.

Comment: Two questions including this one, and you give up so easily?! Your first question needed a little more exposure,  two users replied courteously and defended your question, and you are leaving because of one moderator's action. Perhaps if you had participated, and helped answer the many, many questions that are posted hourly, you might have found more collaboration and received more gratifying feedback.

Comment: This is not the case with the quality of your earlier submission, but it is perhaps sometimes felt that there should be _more_ hoops for people to have to jump through. That having been said, I feel the reasons given for closure at your previous post were spirit-of-the-law rather than letter-of-the-law. As one member said, 'It would be better given as a (quality) answer to the previous question.' But you'll have to stay a while to get a feel of what the natives like. I'm giving it 20 years.

Comment: Oh – and check Mari-Lou A's 'reputation' – and _she_ has the temerity to sling in a '?!'!

Comment: @Blackthorne: I think you're misdirecting your vitriol. If a ***moderator*** wanted to close this question, it would be closed ***instantly***. Ordinary users (with sufficient rep) can ***vote*** to close, but it needs ***five*** of them to close a question. Mods can and do simply close questions unilaterally, but they usually leave it to the voting community. Which at the moment excludes me, because I've reached my daily closevote limit. (If I hadn't, I assure you this question wouldn't be still sitting here with just ***four*** closevotes - it's nothing but an Off Topic peeve :)

Comment: It was closed instantly by one moderator. First because it didn't contain a question and then, after I had changed it and after two members had commented on how useful it was, it was closed. It doesn't matter: I contribute on other language sites. It's just a shame that this forum is structured in a way that hampers the free flow of conversation and exploration.

Comment: Still: your forum, your rules.

Comment: Ooh, go on. Stay. It's always good to have fresh blood in the arena, erm... forum, em... community, erm... society. Society? In any case I do sympathise, and anyone else would have been pi**ed off if their *question* had been closed after only TEN minutes. (I've only just looked at the timestamps and realized this fact) Stick around, and maybe three more users will decide to reopen your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a rant.

Answer (score 12):

You seem to have taken things a tad personally. Even to the extent of referring to people as [*twats*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/twat), a word whose actual meaning I assume you are not aware of and instead meant to write [*twits*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/twit) which is a far less offensive term.

Now, on to your <del>rant</del> question. This site is *not* a forum, this is very important. It is instead a question and answer wiki. Question posts are expected to be just that, *questions*. Your post is indeed both useful and interesting but it is not a question. Even when you added a question to it, it is not a question that is on topic (from our [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> [...]
>
> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

Your question is basically asking what others feel about your very nice chart. That is exactly the kind of opinion seeking that the rule above tries to avoid. Therefore, your question was closed as being off topic because it is.

One of the best things about the Stack Exchange network of sites is that they are all very strict in what they consider on topic. While that may sometimes have the negative effect of blocking useful information such as your post contained, it also has the very positive effect of keeping the sites relevant to their subject matter.

Now, it so happens that a question you wanted to answer had been [protected](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/) because it was attracting too much off topic discussion. This means that new users can't answer it. You can still answer 99% of the question on the site, only a very few are protected.

You had a useful comment to make, so since you couldn't post it as an answer, you did what you would have done in a forum and started a new thread. That's fine on forums but is not how we work here so your question was closed. The SE way of doing things would have been to ask a new question yourself and adding your post as an answer to your own question.

Think of SE as a society (it is). Whenever you move to a new society, you need some time to familiarize yourself with its rules and social norms. You do not know the norms here and have taken umbrage at something that was in no way a personal attack. I also respectfully submit that calling people *twats* is not the best way to start a civil conversation and there is no reason to resort to profanity just because you don't understand how a particular society works.